# HTML Drag and drop API - how do you handle mobile refresh and scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

And jquery is not an option!

So I have this problem with dragging and dropping HTML elements on mobile devices where where dragging doesn't seem to be possible because

1. The browsers "swipe down to refresh" seems to take over
2. Touch scrolling seems to take over

I say seems as I am not even sure it is possible doing it this way. I get the impression that there should be a way to prevent scrolling and swipe refresh during dragging right?

Below is a simple example that can only move boxes below other boxes. But can you do this on mobile?

```js
const dragContainer = document.querySelector(".drag-container");
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
let currentlyDragging;
for (const element of elements) {
    element.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
    element.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter);
}
function dragStart(event) {
    currentlyDragging = event.target;
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.id);
}
function dragEnter(event) {
    if (event.target === currentlyDragging)
        return;
    dragContainer.removeChild(currentlyDragging);
    const target = event.target;
    currentlyDragging = target.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", currentlyDragging);
}
```

```css
.drag-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.draggable {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
  <div class="drag-container">
    <div draggable="true"
         class="draggable a">a</div>
    <div draggable="true"
         class="draggable b">b</div>
    <div draggable="true"
         class="draggable c">c</div>
  </div>
```